# Lifting Upper Semi-Continuous Functions To Grassmannians

Tags: linear-algebra, grassmannians

Let $V$ be a vector space.

Suppose we are given some upper semi-continuous map $\pi:V\rightarrow \bigcup_{k\le d} Gr(V,d)$, i.e, for any $x\in V$ we specify some subspace $\pi(x) \subseteq V$ of dimension no more than $d$, and these vary in a upper semi-continuous manner.

Must there exist a function $\eta$ from $V$ to the grassmannian $Gr(V,d)$ which is continuous/smooth, so that $\eta(x)$ always contains $\pi(x)$ as a subset?

Comment: Can you   explain precisely the statement  *these vary in a upper semi-continuous manner*?  As far I know semi-continuity refers only to real valued maps. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity

Comment: The notion of semi-continuous maps can be extended to set-valued maps. You can read about it here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/131206/what-is-the-definition-of-continuity-of-set-valued-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Take $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $d=1$ and define $\pi$ by $\pi(v)=\text{span}(v)$ if $\|v\|=1$, $\pi(v)=\{0\}$ otherwise. Then $\pi$ is usc and a continuous $\eta$ doesn't exist, as the image of $S^1$ is a nontrivial cocycle in $\text{Gr}(V,1)$.

Note also that $\pi(v)=\text{span}(v)$ for all $v$ is an example of a lsc $\pi$ with no $\eta$.

However, if $\pi:V\to\text{Gr}(V,k)$ is actually continuous for some $k<d$, then such $\eta$ does exist. To see this it is enough to assume $d=k+1$. Then use the contractibility of $V$ to find a no trivial section to the vector bundle $E$ over $V$ given by $E_v=\pi(v)^\perp$ and add it to $\pi$.